# change Fragment View

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have an app with fragments. It works fine.

One of the fragments has a button, and when pressed I want to change the view.

```
public class BikeRecap extends Fragment {

public static Activity activity;
public static Context context;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    activity = getActivity();
    context = activity.getApplicationContext();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bike_recap, container, false);        

    ImageButton details = (ImageButton) item.findViewById(R.id.details);


    details.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              OpenNewView();
          }
    });

    return view;
}
```

OpenNewView() should change the view, so, the user is in the same tab, but the content is different

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a fragment inside a fragment.

Try this code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager2.beginTransaction();
DetailFragment fragment2 = new DetailFragment();
fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack("abc");
fragmentTransaction2.hide(BikeRecap.this);
fragmentTransaction2.add(android.R.id.content, fragment2);
fragmentTransaction2.commit();
```

Comment: I dont want a Fragment inside a Fragment, I want to change what the Fragment shows

Comment: Actually, you can have child fragments as of Android 4.2 and this is also back-ported via the Android Support Library.

Comment: @cocoahero, Really? I didn't know about that, Do you know if have a sample on API Demos?

Comment: @Marckaraujo not sure if there is sample code, but all you have to do is from within your Fragment, call getChildFragmentManager();

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: what is a DetailFragment? I cant find it, is it some package?

Comment: I got it, I know what is a DetailFragment, my new class, so sorry for the question.Thanks for the report, I didn't tried the 4.2 child fragments, because I want it works since 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, pretty easily, do what you are trying to do.  If OpenNewView is implemented by the Activity, instead of by the fragment:

getActivity().openNewView(...)

... then the Activity can easily replace the current fragment with a new one, using the standard transaction mechanism.

G. Blake Meike
Marakana

Programming Android 2ed is now in stores:
http://bit.ly/programmingandroid

Comment: so sorry, but I don't understand you, I ask how to do it, and you told me, "using the standard transaction"?