# Link a class with each fragment layout

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, tablet

I am developing an application for tablet (landscape mode only). Stuck at linking a class with a layout.
In main activity layout there is a permanent left pane (List Fragment) for menu items. And a right pane (Detail fragment frame) for details. For each menu item there is separate layout to display in details frame and also a java file which makes the layout functional (which may include button click listeners for that particular layout). I am able to display particular layout for each menu item dynamically by using following function,

```
View v = inflater.inflate(Values.LAYOUT[positionIndex], container, false);
```

but I cant understand where and how can I link a different class with each layout?

I have followed this hierarchy:

Java files:
Main.java
 
ListFragment.java
DetailFragment.java
Functions_for_item1.java
Functions_for_item2.java
(similarly for n number of items)

XML Layouts:
main.xml 
layout_for_item1.xml
 
layout_for_item2.xml
(layout for n number of items)

layout_for_item1.xml must be linked with Functions_for_item1.java and similarly layout_for_item2.xm2 must be linked with Functions_for_item2.java. How can I achieve this? You help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the "Master-Detail-Flow"-template when creating a new android activity? The generated code does pretty much the same you want to achieve:

In Eclipse -> Your Project -> Your Package -> Right Click -> New -> Other -> Android Activity -> "Master-Detail-Flow"

Then I would create a "DetailFragment" for each item. So basically the solution would be to have a dedicated fragment for each item, since fragments will combine the layout and the functions out-ouf the box...

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering my query. I tried Master-Detail-Flow but it does not allow to have a unique layout for each item. There is a textview which is being changed according to item by .setText(mItem.content) function. But I want the whole layout to be replaced with a new one. For example what if the some more objects need to be added in new layout?

Comment: And you said "Then I would create a 'DetailFragment' for each item". How will you identify which DetailFragment is to be displayed for any item?

Comment: The FragmentActivity which hosts your fragments is able to distinct which fragment should be displayed as "detail fragment" depending on the selected item. So if you select an item in your ListFragment you can change the DetailFragment accordingly. Here is how you can change a Fragment http://stackoverflow.com/a/14379093/2538428. So in your FragmentActivity add something like switch(selectedItem){ case item1: changeFragment(new DetailFragmentForItem1.class); ... }

Comment: One remark: Usually the master-detail pattern is used when you need to display the same type of details in the same way but with differentvalues. Since you require to have distinct layouts and behavior I would go for separated fragments. In the onCreateView-method you can inflate the dedicated layout and in onActicityCreated() you can then add the desired behaviour...